# Output PSD layers as base64 in JSON file using ImageMagick

Tags: php, base64, imagemagick-convert

I have a routine that uses PHP/ImageMagick to loop through a .psd and save the layers as PNG files. I now want to be able to output them as base64 in a JSON object instead without the intermediate step of saving them to a file. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have tried base64_encode() on the layer eg:

```
 foreach ($psd as $no => $layer) {

    // Skip the first layer 

    if (!$no) {
      continue;
    }

    echo base64_encode($layer);
```

but the output doesn't seem to be in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

This command will write a PNG image to base64 in Imagemagick.  Sorry, I do not know how to convert to json.

```
convert lena.png INLINE:lena.txt
```

Comment: Thank you - that's useful but I need to use the PHP notation ...

Comment: If my answer helped, please consider giving it an up-vote

Answer (score 0):

That definitely inspired me. I added

```
$layer->setImageFormat("png");
```

before the base64_encode and it worked.